# Stimulus method connect doesn't load when I navigate on my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I work on a application RoR 7 and I've a problem with my stimulus controllers.

I add different method to move some elements (banners, buttons, text etc.). That works when I refresh my page, but don't when I navigate on it.

I try to find some informations on the documentation or chat, but nothing works.

Check my controller :

```
`
  connect() {
    this.displayBanner();
  }

  displayBanner(){
    this.titleTarget.style.transform = "translateY(0%)"
    this.titleTarget.style.opacity = "1"
    this.btnTarget.style.opacity = "1"
  }
`
```

I want my method displayBanner runs each time I visit a page.

Answer (score 0):

As you reload the page methods works fine, so, you should check your web browser console and check the error messages that occurs when you first access the page.

My guess, It's likely that the problem is related to when the code is running and the elements of the page it is trying to access. JavaScript is fetching page elements that haven't loaded yet or don't exist in the current route. So check all the elements you are considering in your JS file.